# Integrated-circuit identification

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I need help identifying two SMD parts. One says (1G5) and the other says (1P)
 they each have six pins.

[image]

[image]

Comment: These codes usually dont say much and can stand for a wide range of possible devices. Having reverse engineered at least the part of the circuit around them might make it possible to do a better guess.

Comment: Edit your question and try to add the image again.

Comment: The bottom one looks like 165 to me.

Answer (score 1):

1. [The 1P could be one](http://alltransistors.com/smd-search.php?search=1p)  of [several things](http://smdcode.com/en/smd/code/search/?q=1p) You'll have to try matching the circuit around it to the various components.
2. 1G5 isn't coming up anywhere for a 6 pin device.